# Weird error when updated to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, upgrade

I just updated our system to 1.9 and am getting a weird error that I've not been able to resolve.
I can enter the back-end just fine and I can see that we are actually on 1.9 so I know for sure that we are actually up to date.

I firstly thought that it might have been the theme conflicting the problem but that was not the case as I tried changing that as well. Here is the error log that I've got from it.

**The report file:**

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:7281:"Invalid method Mage_Cms_Block_Page::addModelTags(Array
(
    [0] => Mage_Cms_Model_Page Object
        (
            [_cacheTag:protected] => cms_page
            [_eventPrefix:protected] => cms_page
            [_eventObject:protected] => object
            [_resourceName:protected] => cms/page
            [_resource:protected] => 
            [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => cms/page_collection
            [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
            [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [page_id] => 2
                    [title] => iPhone onderdelen en iPad onderdelen | Menko Ubbens
                    [root_template] => one_column
                    [meta_keywords] => iPhone onderdelen, iPad onderdelen, Parts-Repair.nl, Menko Ubbens
                    [meta_description] => iPhone onderdelen nodig? Repareer jouw iPhone of iPad eenvoudig zelf met originele Apple onderdelen of laat de reparatie aan Menko Ubbens over. 
                    [identifier] => home
                    [content_heading] => 
                    [content] => <p>{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" category_id="7" product_count="12" is_random="1" hide_button="0" block_name="Bekijk onze top producten" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml"}}</p>
<p>{{block type="core/template" template="BD/cms/cms_home_content.phtml"}}</p>
<p>{{block type="catalog/product_new" products_count="10" hide_button="0" block_name="Nieuwe producten in onze webshop" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}</p>
                    [creation_time] => 2012-11-28 11:20:11
                    [update_time] => 2015-02-04 08:46:17
                    [is_active] => 1
                    [sort_order] => 0
                    [layout_update_xml] => <!--<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="reports/product_compared" name="home.reports.product.compared" template="reports/home_product_compared.phtml" after="product_viewed">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.compared</alias></action>
    </reference>-->
                    [custom_theme] => 
                    [custom_root_template] => 
                    [custom_layout_update_xml] => 
                    [custom_theme_from] => 
                    [custom_theme_to] => 
                    [store_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                )

            [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
            [_origData:protected] => Array
                (
                    [page_id] => 2
                    [title] => iPhone onderdelen en iPad onderdelen | Menko Ubbens
                    [root_template] => one_column
                    [meta_keywords] => iPhone onderdelen, iPad onderdelen, Parts-Repair.nl, Menko Ubbens
                    [meta_description] => iPhone onderdelen nodig? Repareer jouw iPhone of iPad eenvoudig zelf met originele Apple onderdelen of laat de reparatie aan Menko Ubbens over. 
                    [identifier] => home
                    [content_heading] => 
                    [content] => <p>{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" category_id="7" product_count="12" is_random="1" hide_button="0" block_name="Bekijk onze top producten" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml"}}</p>
<p>{{block type="core/template" template="BD/cms/cms_home_content.phtml"}}</p>
<p>{{block type="catalog/product_new" products_count="10" hide_button="0" block_name="Nieuwe producten in onze webshop" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}</p>
                    [creation_time] => 2012-11-28 11:20:11
                    [update_time] => 2015-02-04 08:46:17
                    [is_active] => 1
                    [sort_order] => 0
                    [layout_update_xml] => <!--<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="reports/product_compared" name="home.reports.product.compared" template="reports/home_product_compared.phtml" after="product_viewed">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.compared</alias></action>
    </reference>-->
                    [custom_theme] => 
                    [custom_root_template] => 
                    [custom_layout_update_xml] => 
                    [custom_theme_from] => 
                    [custom_theme_to] => 
                    [store_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                )

            [_idFieldName:protected] => page_id
            [_isDeleted:protected] => 
            [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
)";i:1;s:3131:"#0 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Block\Page.php(52): Varien_Object->__call('addModelTags', Array)
#1 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Block\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Block_Page->addModelTags(Object(Mage_Cms_Model_Page))
#2 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Block\Page.php(65): Mage_Cms_Block_Page->getPage()
#3 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\local\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(238): Mage_Cms_Block_Page->_prepareLayout()
#4 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#5 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('cms/page', 'cms_page')
#6 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('cms/page', 'cms_page')
#7 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#8 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#9 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#10 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#11 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#12 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#13 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#14 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#15 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#16 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

**Exception.log file:**

```
2015-03-13T10:19:37+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer::addCacheTag(Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => store
            [1] => cms_block
        )

)
)' in C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\lib\Varien\Object.php:653
Stack trace:
#0 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Footer.php(45): Varien_Object->__call('addCacheTag', Array)
#1 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Footer.php(45): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer->addCacheTag(Array)
#2 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\lib\Varien\Object.php(112): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer->_construct()
#3 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(491): Varien_Object->__construct(Array)
#4 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('page/html_foote...', Array)
#5 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_foote...', 'footer')
#6 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_foote...', 'footer')
#7 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#8 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#9 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#10 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#12 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#13 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#14 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#15 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 C:\git-projects\parts-repair-iphone-landbridge\index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

List of extensions we got 
[image: Extensiosn we got]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods that cannot be resolved (`addCacheTag`, `addModelTags`) are defined in the class `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`. This class is usually located in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php`.

Apparently, according to your stack trace, there is a file `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php` which replaces the original core file (really bad practice) and probably misses the aforementioned methods.

Hard to say which extension introduced that file to your system for what reason.

Options are:

- Merge the core file's content into the local copy, maintenance problems will persist.
- Delete the local copy and implement the changes (that were introduced by the local copy) in a less intrusive way.
- Remove all the extension that introduced the local copy and claim your money back.